# Zend Search Lucene HTTP 500 Internal Server Error while bulk indexing on small tables

Tags: zend-framework, lucene, zend-search-lucene

I am just getting started with Zend Search Lucene and am testing on a GoDaddy shared Linux account.  Everything is working - I can create and search Lucene Documents.  The problem is when I try to index my whole table for the first time I get a HTTP 500 Internal Server Error after about 30 seconds.  If I rewrite my query so that I only select 100 rows of my table to index, it works fine.

I have already increased my php memory_limit settings to 128M.  The table I'm trying to index is only 3000 rows and I'm indexing a few columns from each row.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Zend_Search_Lucene does not work very well for large data-sets in my experience. For that reason I switched the search backend to Apache Lucene in a larger project.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting your timeout to something higher than 30seconds (default in php.ini)?  The memory threshold can also be  exceeded easily with 3000 rows depending on what you're indexing.  If you're indexing everything as Text fields, and perhaps you're indexing related data, you can easily gobble that memory up.